# Generics: T extends MyClass vs. T extends MyClass<T>

Tags: java, generics

Is there a semantic difference between these two declaration or is it only syntactic sugar?

`class C<T extends C>`   vs   `class C<T extends C<T>>`

**Background:** I recently answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512202/how-do-you-declare-an-abstract-method-so-that-the-parameter-type-class-is-alway/6512302#6512302) on generics using  the `C<T extends C>` approach and a peer provided a similar answer based on `C<T extends C<T>>`. At  the end, both alternatives provided the same result (in the context of the question asked). I remained curious about the difference between these two constructs.

Is there's a semantic difference? If so, what are the implications and consequences of each approach?

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking about, but the first snippet does include a raw type, meaning that it's not "proper" generic code - `C` should be parameterised with something.  It's my opinion that this would be a hard compiler error were it not for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I know this is not (really) your question either, but there is no **semantic** difference since the program will behave in the same way in both cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure - often these "self types" are used to constrain subtypes to return exactly their own type.  Consider something like the following:

```
public interface Operation {
    // This bit isn't very relevant
    int operate(int a, int b);
}

public abstract class AbstractOperation<T extends AbstractOperation<T>> {
    // Lets assume we might need to copy operations for some reason
    public T copy() {
        // Some clever logic that you don't want to copy and paste everywhere
    }
}
```

Cool - we have a parent class with a useful operator which can be specific to subclasses.  For instance, if we create an `AddOperation`, what can its generic parameters be?  Because of the "recursive" generic definition, this can only be AddOperation giving us:

```
public class AddOperation extends AbstractOperation<AddOperation> {
    // Methods etc.
}
```

And hence the `copy()` method is guaranteed to return an `AddOperation`.  Now lets imagine we're silly, or malicious, or creative, or whatever, and try to define this class:

```
public class SubtractOperation extends AbstractOperation<AddOperation> {
    // Methods etc.

    // Because of the generic parameters, copy() will return an AddOperation
}
```

This will be rejected by the compiler because the generic type isn't within its bounds.  This is quite important - it means that in the parent class, even though we don't know what the concrete type is (and it might even be a class that didn't exist at compile time), the `copy()` method will return an instance of that same subclass.

If you simply went with `C<T extends C>`, then this weird definition of `SubtractOperation` **would** be legal, and you lose the guarantees about what `T` is in that case - hence the subtract operation can copy itself into an add operation.

This isn't so much about protecting your class hierarchy from malicious subclasses, it's more that it gives the compiler stronger guarantees about the types involved.  If you're calling `copy` from another class altogther on an arbitrary `Operation`, one of your formations guarantees that the result will be of the same class, while the other will require casting (and *might* not be a correct cast, as with the SubtractOperation above).

Something like this for example:

```
// This prelude is just to show that you don't even need to know the specific
// subclass for the type-safety argument to be relevant
Set<? extends AbstractOperation> operations = ...;
for (AbstractOperation<?> op : operations) {
    duplicate(op);
}

private <T extends AbstractOperation<T>> Collection<T> duplicate(T operation) {
    T opCopy = operation.copy();
    Collection<T> coll = new HashSet<T>();
    coll.add(operation);
    coll.add(opCopy);

    // Yeah OK, it's ignored after this, but the point was about type-safety! :)
    return coll; 
}
```

The assignment on the first line of `duplicate` to `T` wouldn't be type-safe with the weaker of the two bounds you proposed, so the code wouldn't compile.  *Even if* you define all of the subclasses sensibly.

Comment: You don't reference `Operation` anywhere else within your code - did you want an `implements Operation` somewhere in there?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a class called Animal

```
class Animal<T extends Animal>
```

If T is Dog, it would mean that Dog should be a subclass of Animal< Dog>, Animal< Cat>, Animal< Donkey> anything.

```
class Animal<T extends Animal<T>>
```

In this case if T is Dog, it has to be a subclass of Animal< Dog> and nothing else, i.e. you must have a class

```
class Dog extends Animal<Dog>
```

you can't have

```
class Dog extends Animal<Cat>
```

And even if you have that, you can't use Dog as a type parameter for Animal and you must have

```
class Cat extends Animal<Cat>
```

In many cases there is a lot of difference between the two, especially if you have some constraints applied.

Comment: Yes you can have `class Dog extends Animal<Cat>` in **both** cases as long as `class Cat extends Animal<Cat>`.

Comment: as long as Cat extends Animal <Dog> you mean

Comment: No. I mean that Dog can extend Animal<Cat> as long as Cat extends Animal<Cat>. The generic template just indicates that T should extend Animal<T> and Cat **can** extend Animal<Cat>.

Comment: But then you cant use that Dog directly with Animal. i.e. you can't have class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> where T is specified later on as Dog. because it has to match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there is a semantical difference. Here's a minimal illustration:

```
class C<T extends C> {
}

class D<T extends D<T>> {
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new C<C>();  // compiles
        new D<D>();  // doesn't compile.
    }
}
```

The error is fairly obvious:

> Bound mismatch: The type `D` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends D<T>>` of the type `D<T>`